# Как подсветить недавно вставленную запись в TableView?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, javafx

Эта проблема для меня оказалась довольно сложной. Есть Hibernate. Раньше было написано так, что запись вставлялась в TableView и она сразу же подсвечивалась. 
Сейчас делаю по-другому. Добавляю сразу в БД, потом запускаю вьюшку с TableView, в это время весь список записей читается и вставляется в TableView. После этого, нужно подсветить ту, что я добавил.
Упрощенно делаю так:

```
groupTypeDao.save(groupType);
....
// запускается фрейм
....
List<GroupType> groupTypes = groupTypeDao.findAll();
ObservableList<GroupType> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList(groupTypes);
tableView.setItems(ol);

// подсветка
tableView.getSelectionModel().select(groupType);
```

И ничего не подсвечивается. Я попытался узнать номер строки в tableView и подсветить по номеру.

```
Integer number = tableView.getItems().indexOf(groupType);
```

В итоге, number = -1. 
Т.е. объект в списке объектов tableView не найден. Но он там есть. Копание дальше в дебаггере дало только то, что почему-то из DAO два одинаковых объекта выходят как разные (с разными хэшами). Т.е. если сделать

```
GroupType groupType = groupTypeDao.findById(3);
GroupType groupType1 = groupTypeDao.findById(3);
```

И потом

```
groupType.equals(groupType1)
```

выдаст false.
Также, объекты имеют разные hashCode(). 
Копал дальше. Внутри объекты не отличаются ничем, кроме связей, которые подтягиваются по LasyInitialization. Т.е. в обоих groupType есть поле userAdded, которое указывает на одного и того же юзера (он вообще один в БД), но хэшкоды этой связи опять же разные.

Есть еще один проект, в котором если я напишу также выбор двух одинаковых объектов из БД - они будут одинаковыми. С одинаковыми хэшкодами.
У обоих проектов совершенно одинаковые конфиги, совершенно одинаковые версии Hibernate и MySQL. Я не знаю, куда копать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

P.S.: Более подробно, со скриншотами выложил здесь: http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-gui-javafx/thread1824661.html
Но там тоже желающих (или могущих) помочь нет.

P.P.S: Минимальный пример:

GroupTypeDao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GroupTypeDaoImpl implements GroupTypeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public GroupType findById(Integer id) {

        return (GroupType) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from GroupType where id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", id).uniqueResult();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<GroupType> findAll() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from GroupType").list();
    }
}
```

Если мы сделаем так:

```
List<GroupType> groups = groupTypeDao.findAll();
GroupType groupType = groups.get(3);
int number = groups.indexOf(groupType);
```

то number будет равен 3. Третий элемент списка, все нормально.

Если же мы сделаем так:

```
List<GroupType> groups = groupTypeDao.findAll();
GroupType groupType = groupTypeDao.findById(3);
int number = groups.indexOf(groupType);
```

то number будет равен -1. Т.е. объект в списке не найден.

Т.е. если взять объект из базы, то он не будет найден в списке из той же базы. Да, я согласен, что возможный вариант решения - переопределить equals() и hashCode(). Но в другом проекте такая же операция с такими же настройками проходит на ура. Без всяких переопределений equals() и hashCode().

P.P.S.: решение найдено - переопределять equals() и hashCode(). Причина того, что в другом проекте работает и без переопределения этих методов - гибернейтовский прокси.

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно как Вам помочь и с чего начать. Сделайте минимальный пример, который можно воспроизвести.

Comment: Добавил пример проблемы.

Comment: Добавьте еще код `GroupType`. Ну и вопрос на засыпку: если переопределить hashCode и equals, все работает?

Comment: Это Java, нужно понять, что hibernate в groupTypeDao.findAll() и groupTypeDao.findById(3) возвращает разные экземпляры класса GroupType, переопределять equals() и hashCode() - обязательно, за вас эквивалентность двух разных объектов никто не определит.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, мне уже пояснили почему все это происходит (добавил в конец вопроса).